# Sampling a dataframe according to some rules: balancing a multilabel dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multilabel-classification

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20,30,40],'text':['some text','another text','random stuff', 'my cat is a god'],
                          'A':[0,0,1,1],
                          'B':[1,1,0,0],
                          'C':[0,0,0,1],
                          'D':[1,0,1,0]})
```

Here I have columns from `A`to `D` but my real dataframe has 100 columns with values of `0`and `1`. This real dataframe has 100k reacords.

For example, the column `A` is related to the 3rd and 4rd row of `text`, because it is labeled as `1`.  The Same way, `A` is not related to the 1st and 2nd rows of `text` because it is labeled as `0`.

What I need to do is to sample this dataframe in a way that I have the same or about the same number of features.

In this case, the feature `C` has only one occurrece, so I need to filter all others columns in a way that I have one text with `A`, one `text` with `B`, one `text` with `C`etc..

The best would be:  I can set using for example `n=100`  that means I want to sample in a way that I have 100 records with all the features.

This dataset is a multilabel dataset training and is higly unbalanced,  I am looking for the best way to balance it for a machine learning task.

**Important**:  I don't want to exclude the `0` features.  I just want to have ABOUT the same number of columns with `1` and `0`

For example. with a final data set with 1k records, I would like to have all columns from `A` to the `final_column` and all these columns with the same numbers of `1` and `0`.  To accomplish this I will need to random discard `text` rows and `id` only.

The approach I was trying was to look to the feature with the lowest `1` and `0`  counts and then use this value as threshold.

Edit 1:  One possible way I thought is to use:

```
df.sum(axis=0, skipna=True)
```

Then I can use the column with the lowest sum value as threshold to filter the text column.  I dont know how to do this filtering step

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The exact output you expect is unclear, but assuming you want to get 1 random row per letter with 1 you could reshape (while dropping the 0s) and use `GroupBy.sample`:

```
(df
 .set_index(['id', 'text'])
 .replace(0, float('nan'))
 .stack()
 .groupby(level=-1).sample(n=1)
 .reset_index()
)
```

*NB. you can rename the columns if needed*
output:

```
   id             text level_2    0
0  30     random stuff       A  1.0
1  20     another text       B  1.0
2  40  my cat is a god       C  1.0
3  30     random stuff       D  1.0
```